Microservices No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
I have an application based on microservice architecture. I have Angular used on the frontend, and .Net on the backend. On the backend, I have Contractors and Identity microservices (based on the identity entity framework). The Identity service is responsible for authorizing the Contractors service based on the Bearer token sent. If the token is not sent by the Angular application in the Authorization header, requests to the Contractors service go through correctly, but including the token in the Authorization header causes the following message: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5002/api/v1/Contractors/test' from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. In the Program.cs files of both services it has the code:
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());

Commenting out the code below in the Program.cs file of the Contractors service makes the error disappear, but also makes authorization impossible.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001"; //builder.Configuration["IdentityServer"];//"https://localhost:5001";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
        options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    });


Could you pls go to the launchsetting.json file of the https://localhost:5002 project and then change "iisSettings"/"anonymousAuthentication" to true, then test again?

the "anonymousAuthentication" parameter in the project is already set to true

Change this in your .Net Backend - TokenValidationParameters or code like this
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = false;
        ValidAudience ="https://localhost:4200";
    };

and on the jwt token generated by your angular it should be present when you try to decode in Jwt.io website
"aud":"https://localhost:4200"

Add this on your header on your Angular requests:
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://localhost:5002"

or
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"

    


My token is generated in the Identity service and the Angular application only stores it after logging in and attaches it to requests
